# React redirect with parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

We are in the process of migrating from an old system written in angularJS to a new system, the problem however is that we have some url's that are specifically written with a double slash ie `"/#/work/customerDetails//:id"` now these urls do not work with `useResolvedPath`, as its being normalized and therefore the double slash removed. So we want to put a redirect in place, which looks for the old urls (for the bits of code that still uses them) and redirects them to the new url (replacing the double slash with a single slash, so that the useResolvedPath will work correctly).

We currently use a simple hash router in our react app (which is part of a single-spa microservice), however, every option that I can think of to use in the redirect does not seem to work:

```
const router = createHashRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="work" element={<Root />}>
      <Route
        path="customerDetails//:id"
        element={<Navigate to="/#/work/customerDetails/:id" />}
      />
      <Route
        path="customerDetails/:id"
        element={<SiteAccount />}
      >
        {siteAccountRoutes}
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redirect to a nested hashroute and the new target won't have the `id` path parameter of the current route "forwarded" to it.

Create a small component that can sniff the current route params, and apply them to a redirection target path.

Example:

```
import {
  Navigate,
  useParams,
  generatePath
} from "react-router-dom";

const Redirect = ({ to }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  return <Navigate to={generatePath(to, params)} replace />;
};
```

Render `Redirect` with a new target path to the sibling `"/work/customerDetails/:id"` route.

```
<Route path="work" element={<Root />}>
  <Route
    path="customerDetails//:id"
    element={<Redirect to="../customerDetails/:id" />}
  />
  <Route path="customerDetails/:id" element={<SiteAccount />}>
    {siteAccountRoutes}
  </Route>
</Route>
```